# Kubernetes NGINX Ingress Controller Failure using Helm on AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, helm, aks

When going through the setup of a K8 ingress controller, which is documented [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls#)

I am unable to get past the step of "Create an Ingress Controller"
During the Helm command step and placing the command in debug mode, I see there is a timeout on one of the steps:

> failed pre-install: timed out waiting for the condition

After reviewing the K8 POD logs, I found that the K8 system is unable to connect to the registry due to an auth error. The following output has been modified for security reasons but shows the error

```
Failed to pull image "myregistry.azurecr.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.5.1@sha256:...90bd8068": [rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image "....azurecr.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen@sha256:....9b9e90bd8068": failed to resolve reference "myregistry.azurecr.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen@sha256:...190b1dcbcb9b9e90bd8068": ....azurecr.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen@sha256:...9b9e90bd8068: not found, rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "myregistry.azurecr.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen@sha256:...dcbcb9b9e90bd8068": failed to resolve reference "myregistry.azurecr.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen@sha256:...b9b9e90bd8068": failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized]
```

I have verified that the images are located in the container registry based on the "az acr import" command, and that if I do a standard K8 deployment using "kubectl" , the k8 is able to connect to the acr. I have also verified the connection between the cluster and the registry using the following command it works as expected:

```
az aks check-acr -n <cluster> -g <rg>  --acr <acr>
```

This failure only occurs when using the helm command.

### EDIT

After researching this more, I found the following article

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68949434/installing-nginx-ingress-controller-into-aks-cluster-cant-pull-image-from-azu

It appears there is a problem with the digest. I added/replaced the following in the helm command:

```
--set controller.image.digest="sha256:e9fb216ace49dfa4a5983b183067e97496e7a8b307d2093f4278cd550c303899" \
--set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.digest="sha256:950833e19ade18cd389d647efb88992a7cc077abedef343fa59e012d376d79b7" \
```

However, when running the modified helm command, the PODs are in an error state with the following error

```
unknown flag: --controller-class
```

I tried setting the env variable CONTROLLER_TAG=v1.0.0, as documented in the  article but this does not help

Another solution is to set the version number: 3.36.0 in the command. This is successful but requires a downgraded version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reaching out to the MS document site feedback, they provided me with the following fix for this document

```
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/80321
```

After rolling back and reapplying the modified changes, the command was successful. The key was to remove the pod using the helm uninstall command:

```
helm uninstall nginx-ingress --namespace ingress-basic
```

Then removing the ACR repositories from your ACR:

```
jettech/kube-webhook-certgen
defaultbackend-amd64
jetstack/cert-manager-controller
jetstack/cert-manager-webhook
jetstack/cert-manager-cainjector
```

which were created with the "az acr import" command and then rerunning the modified commands.

Hopefully someone finds this of value

Answer (score 0):

disable auth in your ACR container registry for a while :

```
az acr update --name my-acr-registry-name --anonymous-pull-enabled true
```

re-execute the helm chart and
re enable the auth in your registry as the controller is created

```
az acr update --name my-acr-registry-name --anonymous-pull-enabled false
```

no need to change version or others.
This will save your day .
For those of you who think that having an acr container registry public exposed for 9 seconds (the time the ingress controller is executed)will cause a nuclear war ,you can whitelist only known networks in networking section of your acr in order to prevent undesiderable access